# Ejecutar un método cada cierta hora vuejs

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

estoy desarrollando una aplicación para una Tablet en **NativeScript-vue** y necesito ejecutar o llamar un método a las 23:00 Hrs de la tablet.
Ya logre capturar la hora del dispositivo pero no logro hacer la ejecución del método la hora dicha,

```
var fecha = new Date();
alert("Hora: "+fecha.getHours()+"\nMinuto: "+fecha.getMinutes());
```

Como es NativeScript- **Vue** .. supongo que funcionaria igual en Vue.js ya que es la misma estructura en el componente .vue

Comment: En que metodo esta ese codigo? la aplicacion esta siempre abierta? Tene en cuenta que por mas que sea nsvue, sigue siendo como una aplicacion que tiene que tener un metodo que mira la hora a cada rato...

Comment: sisi la aplicación esta siempre abierta y ese código lo puse en el mounted

Comment: El mounted solo se ejecuta al momento de cargar la pagina. Si no hay un metodo que se ejecute cada cierto tiempo, no va a pasar...

Comment: exacto... emm tu crees que si hago que se ejecute el método cada 5 segundos y mediante un if compare si es la hora adecuada para proceder a actuar el código completo? jeje se ve raro pero creo que funcionaria

Comment: Crease o no, el metodo es asi. Salvo que la tablet o el telefono tengun un metodo automatico para avisarte (como si fuera un servicio de windows). Lo cual desconozco...

Answer (score 1):

Usa la función setInterval() nativa de javascript para que pregunte cada minuto si ya es hora de ejecutarse la función que quieres:

```html
 

//Recuerda que esta función se ejecuta en mili segundos por 
//eso multiplico (1000 * 60) para que se ejecute cada minuto

setInterval(() => {
  if(horaSistema === 23:00){
    nombreDetuFuncion();
  }
}, (1000 * 60));
```